# Create a new object using inheritance

Tags: inheritance, symfony1, admin-generator

I'm developing a new module for an application based in the admin generator.

Once the designed data model has some inheritance relations (`Authorization`, `AuthorizationA`, `AuthorizationB`), I would like to know how can I create new objects for each entity?

Comment: Do you mean" how to create instances of this clases??"

Answer (score 0):

When you are using inheritance you should use setupInheritance method of basic class (for form and filters) to customize inheritance child classes.

Do not use such code:

```
configure(...) {
  parent::configure(...);
}
```

If you wnat to create one admin-gernerator module and want to be able to manage object for both types you should to generate admin module under basic model and customize form of bacis class: add choice widget (one of AuthorizationA, AuthorizationB).